# Replace specific string in large string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm writing a small WPF Application which helps my company to update costumer projects. I have a list of SQL-Files which I have to execute. Now these scripts are always written with a "USE [Insert_Database]". I read the whole content of a script into a string, but my Replace method doesn't seem to do anything.

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
content.Replace("Insert_Database", Database.Name);
SqlScriptsList.Add(new SqlScriptModel {Name = Path.GetFileName(file), Path = file, ScriptContent = content});
```

Comment: A little suggestion - if string is really big and you will do a lot of replacements, I'd recommend you to search for rope implementaton - a nice structure to perform modifcations on large strings.

Comment: Strings are immutable. The contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.Replace` returns the modified `string`, so it should be:

```
content = content.Replace(....);
```

> This method does not modify the value of the current instance.
>   Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldValue
>   are replaced by newValue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace function as follow on strings

```
str = str.Replace("oldstr","newstr");
```

if oldstr is found in the str then it will be replaced by new str

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using new value when you call replace.

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
content = content.Replace("Insert_Database", Database.Name);
SqlScriptsList.Add(new SqlScriptModel {Name = Path.GetFileName(file), Path = file, ScriptContent = content});
```

for reference: the MSDN doc for replace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx